# MAC address is not displaying only in Nexus phone

Tags: android, android-widget, wifi

I created a Widget which displays WiFi details. For the nexus phone only MAC address is not displaying. The code which I am using to display MAC is given below.

```
myWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
mMacIp = myWifiInfo.getMacAddress();
```

For every other mobile it is displaying correctly.

Comment: which version of android u r using to code?

Answer (score 0):

Is the wifi off? (You can't get a MAC address of a disabled wifi).

Have you added the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yea. For every other phones and Emulator also i am getting the MAC address.